# Want to receive GCM even if Background Data is off

Tags: android, notifications, google-cloud-messaging

My implementation of the GCM works normally when the app is in the background or shut down, as is should be.

But when the "Background data" (in the "Account and Sync" setting of the device) is disabled, I do not receive GCM notifications anymore.

I am not 100% sure if this is the sole reason is the "Background data" setting, but based on our experiment, it seems like the "Background data" is the variable for whether the app receives the GCM or not.

**My First Question:**

Is this an expected behavior, or are we doing something fundamentally wrong?

**My Second Question:**

I have heard from a fellow programmer that some people create a new Service to live in the background and listen to incoming GCMs.

I am still trying to figure out the logic behind this, but does it sound like a viable option?

Sorry for being vague in my question.

I am still struggling with the design of the solution to this problem so...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the android manual :

> Background data controls whether applications and services can
>   transmit data when you are not working with them directly

It doesn't explicitly say that background data is GCM but there are lots of evidence and a bunch of threads that all say :

> GCM messages are not delivered when background data is disabled

you can easily test it yourself, disable background data, go to the web version of play store install an app. You will only receive it when you re enable the background data. If not even google can make it, then likely you wont be able either.

If you still think you saw applications receiving GCM messages when background data is disabled it can be because of :

- In newer android phones you can enable background data per application, probably it was enabled for an another app
- Probably what you saw was not a GCM notification, but the application falls back to polling the server when GCM is not available

If you are still not convinced then set up you phone to use a proxy server like burp suite on your machine and you will be able to see what other apps are doing on the network.

Comment: Thank you!
A famous app is actually able to receive notifications even when "background data" is off. When I checked the running processes, it had an extra process (a service perhaps?), and I am thinking that that is receiving the notifications via polling or some socket-like scheme.
I will look into it using a proxy server as you have recommended.

Comment: Just for the benefit of the public once you figured it out please share the result.

Answer (score 3):

In the same way that Google Play requires background data enabled ***[Google Play](http://support.google.com/googleplay/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=1663315)***, I guess GCM do so.

When you try to acces to GCM and there is no account registered on the phone an error ACCOUNT_MISSING is returned by the GCM services, and when you detect it you should redirect to the ACCOUNT_SETTINGS so users could add a google mail.
After that, you will have to detect if that background data is enabled using the ConnectivityManager function ***[getBackgroundDataSetting()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/ConnectivityManager.html#getBackgroundDataSetting%28%29)***.

Take care of it, it was deprecated on >= 14 API, you will have to use getActiveNetworkInfo() instead to see if apperas as disconnected because the user has disabled background data.

Other way if you see the last link is registering a listener with the filter ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED (but deprecated on API 16).

```
IntentFilter intentFilter = new IntentFilter(); 
intentFilter.addAction(ConnectivityManager.ACTION_BACKGROUND_DATA_SETTING_CHANGED);
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I will take your advice in when implementing a way to lead the users to the "settings".  But I have just recently discovered that there are other applications which are able to receive GCM notifications even when the "background data" is off, and I am hoping for a solution in that direction.